# Как DAO класс переделать в JPA

Tags: java, jpa, dao

Мой класс DAO, как его можно реализовать в JPA чтобы я мог добавить в свой спринг проект.

```
package dao;

import entity.Student;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseDAO {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db_newnew?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=GMT";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "123456";

    private static final String GET_ALL_STUDENTS_QUERY
            = "SELECT * FROM student;";

    private static final String INSERT_STUDENT_QUERY
            = "INSERT INTO student (name, surname) VALUES(?,?);";

    private static final String DELETE_STUDENT_QUERY = "DELETE FROM student WHERE id = ?;";

    private static final String UPDATE_STUDENT_QUERY = "UPDATE student SET image = ? WHERE id = ?;";

    private String GET_STUDENT_IMAGE_QUERY = "SELECT image FROM student WHERE id = ?;";

    private Connection conn;

    public DatabaseDAO() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> readAllStudentsFromDB() {
        ArrayList<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(GET_ALL_STUDENTS_QUERY)) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String firstName = rs.getString("name");
                String lastName = rs.getString("surname");
                String patron = rs.getString("patron");
                Date date = rs.getDate("birthday");
                LocalDate birthday = null;
                if (date != null) {
                    birthday = date.toLocalDate();
                }
                Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, patron, birthday);
                student.setId(id);
                student.setImage(rs.getString("image"));
                result.add(student);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public int insertStudentIntoDB(String name, String surname) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt
                = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_STUDENT_QUERY, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {

            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.setString(2, surname);

            stmt.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (keys.next()) {
                return keys.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public boolean deleteStudentFromDB(int id) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(DELETE_STUDENT_QUERY)) {
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            int rowsDeleted = stmt.executeUpdate();
            return rowsDeleted > 0;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void updateStudentImage(int id, String fullPath) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_STUDENT_QUERY)) {
            stmt.setString(1, fullPath);
            stmt.setInt(2, id);

            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String readStudentImagePath(int id) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(GET_STUDENT_IMAGE_QUERY)) {
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getString("image");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это очень хороший вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA без Entity в Spring это что-то странное.
Поэтому:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data //from lombok, for generate getters, setters, etc
public class Student {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "patron")  
private String patron;

@Column(name = "birthday")
private Date birthday;

}
```

JPA:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

Как это работает:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor //lombok
@Service
public class StudentService {

private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

public void someExample(){
Student student = studentRepository.findById(12);
student.setName("some_new_name");

//readAllStudentsFromDB
studentRepository.findAll();
//insertStudentIntoDB 
studentRepository.save(new Student());
//deleteStudent
studentRepository.deleteById(1);
//update
studentRepository.save(student);
}
}
```

Читаем: [Оф.дока](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: @АдильКабдыгазинов 
"Получается для каждого нужно отдельный класс?":
Да. Для каждой Entity и Repository этой сущности.
"Отдельный пакет создать специальный для базы данных?":
Подобный пакет и его наличие, обычно, обусловлен структурой пакетов на проекте. Может назваться persistence и содержать сущности и репозитории.
"Свой DAO класс оставлять?":
Дело ваше. Но если Spring то и спользуйте его возможности везде. Либо везде испоьзуйте DAO.
"Можете скинуть свою gmail почту хочу кое что спросить":
К сожелению - нет) я не веду частных консультаций, отвечаю только когда есть время и желание.